# Amend Label Property In Code

Tags: winforms, ironpython

I have a very simple Iron Python / Windows Form application. When the application starts it adds a selection of labels in an array (this is working from a CSV file)

```html
#Create Label for each Site
for s in sites:
    
    if lasty == 682:
        lasty = 0
        lastx = lastx + 125

    sitename = str(s) #Convert Name into a String
    elementname = sitename.replace(" ","") + "Label"
    element = Label()
    element.Name = elementname
    element.Text = str(sitename)
    element.Parent = self
    element.Location = Point(lastx,lasty)

    labels.append(element) #add each element to the list

    lasty = lasty + 22
    pass
```

This is working fine. I then have a definition which runs another loop and depending on the result I would like it to change the colour of the label. Let's say Red for fail, Green for OK, Yellow for warning.

However I cannot seem to link to these labels by the element name I gave them

For example I would think that `SiteNameLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green` would turn that label green. However this fails and halts the program.

Any ideas? Most probably a simple question but I can't find anything about this online.

Here is the error:

`'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipyw64.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Dynamic\v4.0_1.1.1.21__7f709c5b713576e1\Microsoft.Dynamic.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Scripting\v4.0_1.1.1.21__7f709c5b713576e1\Microsoft.Scripting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\IronPython\v4.0_2.7.6.3__7f709c5b713576e1\IronPython.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\IronPython.Modules\v4.0_2.7.6.3__7f709c5b713576e1\IronPython.Modules.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.SQLite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs\IronPython.Wpf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'Snippets.scripting'. 
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in IronPython.Modules.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'Snippets.debug.scripting'. 
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\ISymWrapper\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ISymWrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ipyw64.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ipyw64.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException' in IronPython.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException' in Snippets.debug.scripting
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException' in Snippets.debug.scripting
Exception thrown: 'IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException' in Snippets.debug.scripting
The program '[9416] ipyw64.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).`

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive when trying to change the color of a label?

Comment: I have added the error to the original question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **SiteNameLabel** as object reference. You must obtain reference to Label from Controls collection of your form. See following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')

from System.Drawing import *
from System.Windows.Forms import *

class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        myLabel = Label()
        myLabel.Location = Point(10, 10)
        myLabel.Text = "EXAMPLE LABEL"
        myLabel.Name = "myLabel"
        self.Controls.Add(myLabel)

        # later you can find label by name this way:
        self.Controls["myLabel"].ForeColor = Color.Green

Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

form = MyForm()
Application.Run(form)
```

Note: when you use WinForms designer (in C# project example), it generates form members with control names, so you can access them as you tried. But this is only applicable to controls added at design time.